# Extension UItextField to set rightView

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I wan to use a func to setRightView by the String. When I use this function. It said "Cannot assign value of type '()' to type 'String?'". How to solve this issue? Thanks.

```
extension UITextField {
    func setRightView(name: String) {
        let rightView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(
        x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
        rightView.image = UIImage(named: name)
        self.rightView = rightView
        self.rightViewMode = .always
    }
}
```

I use this function by this.

```
class NotificationSearchInsuranceViewController: UIViewController{

@IBOutlet weak var insuranceCompanyTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var fromEffectiveDateTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var toEffectiveDateTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var toUpgradeDateTextField: UIStackView!
@IBOutlet weak var jobRateTextField: UITextField!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    fromEffectiveDateTextField.setRightView(name: "icon_dropdown")
}
```

Comment: Please show actual code and error.

Comment: Show us where you get the error. I don't see any optional String being involved here.

Comment: @AndreasOetjen Sorry, I didn't copy the right code in my article. Although I use fromEffectiveDateTextField.setRightView(name:"icon_dropdown") it still show the message

Comment: I see, but I don't get the error. If you get the error at `fromEffectiveDateTextField.setRightView(name: "icon_dropdown")`, you could try to comment this line and check if there are any other compiler errors around – sometimes Xcode get's confused and reports strange errors.

Comment: @AndreasOetjen Thanks for your quick response. I found that I comment out too many lines and leave one line "toEffectiveDateTextField.text = ". So it seems that my fromEffectiveDateTextField.setRightView(name: "icon_dropdown") assign to that textfield. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should use it, by signature, as follows

`fromEffectiveDateTextField.setRightView(name: "icon_dropdown")`

or if you want to keep usage "as is" you need to change signature, as follows

```
extension UITextField {
    func setRightView(_ name: String) {
    //               ^^^ here !!
    // .. other code here
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I found the mistake I made.